# how to set company name and job title for contact using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I tried the following code, it shows an error.
Can anyone please help me to get the solution.

```
function SetCompany(){
var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactByName('FirstName LastName');
var company = contacts[0].getCompanies()[0];
company.setCompanyName('ACME Corp');
company.setJobTitle('Manager');
Logger.log('details set');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
function SetCompany(){
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByName('FirstName LastName');
  if(typeof contacts[0].getCompanies()[0]=="undefined"){
    var company = contacts[0].addCompany('ACME Corp', 'Manager');
  }
  else{
    var company = contacts[0].getCompanies()[0];

    company.setCompanyName('ACME Corp');
    company.setJobTitle('Manager');
  }
    Logger.log('details set');
}
```

Comment: @user3409066 if it fit, you should validate it!